# Should I place buildings from the scientific faction over the larger piles of resource?

Tags: offworld-trading-company

When playing as the scientific faction, you can place buildings that need some resource over a tile that has that resource. It will then extract what it needs by itself. Will placing the buildings over the larger resource piles yield more goods or have any advantage over placing it on the tiles with low resources?

Answer (score 2):

Based on my testing the output is the same for the glass kiln and other buildings you place over input resources. Doing so is advisable when you do not need to harvest the resource directly (it's not a rarity to leverage) and to prevent other factions from reaching these resources.